# Overriding Knockout View-Model function

Tags: backbone.js, knockout.js, overriding, extend

I am using knockout and backbone in my application. My test-view.js look like this:

```
define([
  "knockout",
  "./base",
  "./../viewmodels/test-vm",
  "text!./../templates/test-template.html"
],

function(ko, BaseView, TestViewModel, template) {

  var TestView = BaseView.extend({
    template: template,

    initialize: function() {
      this.viewModel = new TestViewModel();
    },

    render: function(){
      this.$el.html(template);
      return this;
    },

    postRender: function() {
      ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel, this.el);
    }
  });

  return TestView;
});
```

test-template.html:

```
<button class="btn"  data-bind="click: test">test</button>
```

and test-vm.js as follows:

```
define([],
  function() {

    function TestViewModel() {
      var self = this;

      self.test = function () {
        alert("in test view model");
      };
    }

    return TestViewModel;
  });
```

When I click button, self.test is invoked. My question is how can I extend TestViewModel in another file and override test function to do some specific things? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any particular reason to use `data-bind` as opposed to `events: {'click': 'viewModel.test'}` on the view? Also, just curious; why use knockout and backbone?

Comment: Well, I didn't start building application from the beginning. It already use backbone and knockout and also data-bind's. I was trying to create new viewmodel and load base (TestViewModel) using require but every time I click on the button base method is invoked. 

example:

`code` define([
    "./test-vm"],
  function(BaseViewModel) {
    function ExtendedTestViewModel() {
      var self = this;
      BaseViewModel.apply(self);
      self.aaa = function() {
        alert("in extended view model");
      };
     }
    ExtendedTestViewModel.prototype = new BaseViewModel();
  });

Comment: also for events: {'click': 'viewModel.test'} I would use data-bind="events: {'click': 'viewModel.test'}" right?

Comment: I could not manage to edit my previous comment, but self.aaa is typo. It is actually self.test

Comment: No, `events: {'click':..` would be inside the `TestView`. Why don't you make a jsfiddle example app so i can play with it and get working for you, i just dont want to spend the time to set it all up. But if *you* take the time to do it, i'll help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason you can't use the commonly used "Classical inheritance with `Object.create`" approach as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

```js
// Define the base class
var TestViewModel = function () {
  this.sharedProperty = true;
};

TestViewModel.prototype.test = function() {
  log("testing TestViewModel");
};

// Define the extended class
var ExtendedTestViewModel = function() {
  TestViewModel.call(this);
};

// Copy the prototype and reset the constructor
ExtendedTestViewModel.prototype = Object.create(TestViewModel.prototype);
ExtendedTestViewModel.constructor = ExtendedTestViewModel;

// Override the inherited `test` function
ExtendedTestViewModel.prototype.test = function() {
  // To call the base method: 
  // (skip this if you want to completely override this function)
  TestViewModel.prototype.test.call(this);
  
  // Add functionality:
  log("testing ExtendedTestViewModel");
};

// Create an instance
var etvm = new ExtendedTestViewModel();

// This will log both the inherited message, as well as the extended message
etvm.test();

// ExtendedTestViewModel has all properties that are in TestViewModel
log(etvm.sharedProperty);

// utils
function log(msg) {
  var pre = document.createElement("pre");
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(pre);
};
```

Comment: yes, that actually works. but in my implementation the problem lies here:  this.viewModel = new TestViewModel(); I need to find a way to checkout whether the extension exist and to init viewModel with extended view model. any ideas about that? thanks for all the answers

Comment: Perhaps something like: `var PreferredVM = (typeof ExtendedTestViewModel === "undefined") ? TestViewModel : ExtendedTestViewModel; var vm = new PreferredVM();` It seems to me that you should know whether an extension exists though...